# How to show that this function is onto

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set $A$ and let $g$ be a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set $B$ and $h$ a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to the union of $A$ and $B$ defined by $h(n)=f(\frac{n+1}{2})$ if $n$ is odd, $h(n)=g(\frac{n}{2})$ if $n$ is even.

Show that h is onto.

I have tried to solve it. Please you can help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You must show that for any $y\in A\cup B,$ there is some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $h(m)=y.$ Proceed by cases, depending on whether $y\in A$ or $y\in B.$ (Why do we need both cases? Why aren't there any other cases to consider?)

Since $f:\Bbb N\to A$ and $g:\Bbb N\to B$ are bijections, then in particular, they are both **onto.** This means (for example) that for any $y\in A,$ there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(m)=y.$ You will have to use that fact to prove the above.